# CentOS connect to the internet

Tags: centos

I installed CentOS, but it didn't automatically connect to the internet. Is that the normal behavior? I have Ethernet Broadband Router DI-604 and WebStar DPX2203 series Cablemodem with EMTA . What should I do to connect to the internet?

Update:

A cousin told me my ethernet adapter or network board will depend on my motherboard. My computer upgrade document says the motherboard is GBabyte video onboard. I heard GBabyte's network adapters are GBabit or Realtek.

In CentOS, System -> Administration -> Network -> New -> Ethernet, first, only "Other Network Board" was listed, so I selected it and clicked Next, then there wasn't GBabit, but there was Realtek, so I selected Realtek.

I heard with Net Virtua selecting dhcp the things first answered asked me to tell first answerer are automatically configured.

So I tried Realtek with `dhcp`, but `eth0` wasn't found.

See asterisks:

we didn't upgrade that time, the motherboard is Asus. `/sbin/lspci -v` shows that the Ethernet controller is *Atheros L2, subsystem is Asustek*.

ifconfig output:

```
lo    Link encap:Loopback Local  
      inet end.: 127.0.0.1  Masc:255.0.0.0
      endereço inet6: ::1/128 Escopo:Máquina
      UP LOOPBACKRUNNING  MTU:16436  Métrica:1
      RX packets:2509 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2509 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      colisões:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:2650372 (2.5 MiB)  TX bytes:2650372 (2.5 MiB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      inet end.: 192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
      endereço inet6: fe80::200:Firefox:fe00:0/64 Escopo:Link
      UP BROADCASTRUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      colisões:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:7306 (7.1 KiB)

xenbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      UP BROADCASTRUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      colisões:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

dhclient output:

```
bash: /sbin/dhclien: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
[root@localhost deltrem]# /sbin/dhclient
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client V3.0.5-RedHat
Copyright 2004-2006 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit http://www.isc.org/sw/dhcp/

/sbin/dhclient-script: configuration for xenbr0 not found. Continuing with defaults.
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions: line 78: xenbr0: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
/sbin/dhclient-script: configuration for veth3 not found. Continuing with defaults.
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions: line 78: veth3: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
/sbin/dhclient-script: configuration for vif0.3 not found. Continuing with defaults.
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions: line 78: vif0.3: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
/sbin/dhclient-script: configuration for veth2 not found. Continuing with defaults.
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions: line 78: veth2: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
/sbin/dhclient-script: configuration for vif0.2 not found. Continuing with defaults.
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions: line 78: vif0.2: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
/sbin/dhclient-script: configuration for veth1 not found. Continuing with defaults.
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions: line 78: veth1: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
/sbin/dhclient-script: configuration for vif0.1 not found. Continuing with defaults.
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions: line 78: vif0.1: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
/sbin/dhclient-script: configuration for veth0 not found. Continuing with defaults.
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions: line 78: veth0: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
/sbin/dhclient-script: configuration for vif0.0 not found. Continuing with defaults.
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions: line 78: vif0.0: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
/sbin/dhclient-script: configuration for virbr0 not found. Continuing with defaults.
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions: line 78: virbr0: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
Listening on LPF/xenbr0/00:00:00:00:00:00
Sending on   LPF/xenbr0/00:00:00:00:00:00
Listening on LPF/veth3/00:00:00:00:00:00
Sending on   LPF/veth3/00:00:00:00:00:00
Listening on LPF/vif0.3/fe:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox
Sending on   LPF/vif0.3/fe:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox
Listening on LPF/veth2/00:00:00:00:00:00
Sending on   LPF/veth2/00:00:00:00:00:00
Listening on LPF/vif0.2/fe:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox
Sending on   LPF/vif0.2/fe:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox
Listening on LPF/veth1/00:00:00:00:00:00
Sending on   LPF/veth1/00:00:00:00:00:00
Listening on LPF/vif0.1/fe:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox
Sending on   LPF/vif0.1/fe:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox
Listening on LPF/veth0/00:00:00:00:00:00
Sending on   LPF/veth0/00:00:00:00:00:00
Listening on LPF/vif0.0/fe:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox
Sending on   LPF/vif0.0/fe:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox:Firefox
Listening on LPF/virbr0/00:00:00:00:00:00
Sending on   LPF/virbr0/00:00:00:00:00:00
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on xenbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
DHCPDISCOVER on veth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on veth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on veth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on veth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on veth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on xenbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
DHCPDISCOVER on veth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
DHCPDISCOVER on veth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on veth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
DHCPDISCOVER on veth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
DHCPDISCOVER on veth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
DHCPDISCOVER on veth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
DHCPDISCOVER on xenbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
DHCPDISCOVER on veth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
DHCPDISCOVER on veth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19
DHCPDISCOVER on veth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
DHCPDISCOVER on veth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
DHCPDISCOVER on xenbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20
DHCPDISCOVER on veth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
DHCPDISCOVER on veth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPDISCOVER on xenbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
DHCPDISCOVER on veth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
DHCPDISCOVER on virbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
DHCPDISCOVER on veth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPDISCOVER on veth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
DHCPDISCOVER on veth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
DHCPDISCOVER on xenbr0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 2
DHCPDISCOVER on vif0.2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 2
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
/sbin/dhclient-script: configuration for veth2 not found. Continuing with defaults.
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions: line 78: veth2: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
```

Update:

Installing Atheros L2. make install says:

```
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.18-194.el5xen/build SUBDIRS=/home/deltrem/l2/src modules
make[1]: Entrando no diretório `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-194.el5-xen-i686'
  CC [M]  /home/deltrem/l2/src/at_main.o
In file included from /home/deltrem/l2/src/at.h:30,
                 from /home/deltrem/l2/src/at_main.c:28:
/home/deltrem/l2/src/kcompat.h:1084: error: redefinition of typedef ‘irq_handler_t’
include/Linux/interrupt.h:67: error: previous declaration of ‘irq_handler_t’ was here
make[2]: ** [/home/deltrem/l2/src/at_main.o] Erro 1
make[1]: ** [_module_/home/deltrem/l2/src] Erro 2
make[1]: Saindo do diretório `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-194.el5-xen-i686'
make: ** [default] Erro 2
```

Take a look here too:

> http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/Linux-networking-3/unable-to-activate-eth0-attansic-l2-on-centos-5-1-a-619969/

Comment: Please post the output of ifconfig and dhclient.

Comment: both are command not found

Comment: `/sbin/ifconfig` ?

Comment: Both worked. I'm trying to install the Atheros L2 driver too, but it looks like my dad's computer has a virus, because my pendrive had a file after formatted.

Comment: ok John question updated with ifconfig and dhclient output

Comment: click edit in my question to see them formatted

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to connect?

Are you able to connect to or ping the router?

What is the logical IP configuration (the CentOS box's IP address, netmask, broadcast address, route; similar info for the router)?

What about the physical hookup?  What cables are connected to what ports, and what's the hardware configuration?  (E.g., crossover or straight cable?  And hooking up a 10BaseT half-duplex card to a GigE only port will not work regardless of the cable.)

Answer (score 0):

Check these two commands:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.122.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.122.255 up  
route add default gw 192.168.122.1
```